# Does converting the synchronous function to an asynchronous function that does no asynchronous job under the hood bring about a performance loss?

Tags: javascript, async-await

That is if I want to rewrite a function that is given below

```
  getDefaultNodes(){
    return this.defaultNodes;
  }
engine.js
-----------------------------
  const defaultNodes = engine.getDefaultNodes();
the place where its method is called.
```

as

```
  async getDefaultNodes(){
    return this.defaultNodes;
  }
engine.js
-----------------------------
  const defaultNodes = await engine.getDefaultNodes();
the place where its method is called.
```

Does this cause a performance issue? If yes, to what extent?

Comment: I would _guess_ that the first one just returns the `defaultNodes` object, whereas the second one returns a promise that resolves to the `defaultNodes` objects.  There's a penalty there that must be paid on both ends.  Once by the function returning the promise, and again by the caller consuming the promise.  Even if the promise just says, "no need to wait, I got your defaultNodes right here.`  Very tiny penalty.

Comment: JavaScript is parsed and then optimized and interpreted in a loop. A good optimizer could probably generate the same bytecode for both codes. I guess it depends on the optimizer.

Comment: Why would you make an async function when it's not necessary? What benefit are you expecting?

Comment: It would be better to send those comments as answers so that I can mark them as an appropriate answers.

Comment: @Andy This is not the point we discuss.

Comment: Well, it should be. Don't go arbitrarily converting your functions to async without needing to.

Comment: @Andy No, please leave the title because you make people stray from the point.

Comment: Your question asks "I want to rewrite a function". My comments are "don't, if it's not necessary."

Comment: We're talking about a hypothesis, the sentence starts with "if" in case you don't see it.

Comment: I suggest reading [this part](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#await-under-the-hood) of the v8 dev blog.

Comment: Fine. "Your question asks "If I want to rewrite a function". My comments are "don't, if it's not necessary." You haven't explained _why_ you want to do this. Given your code in your question you shouldn't. It's pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this bring about a performance loss?

Yes. There's some overhead in creating the promise, resolving it, waiting for it, breaking the code apart on the `await`, and scheduling continuations on the microtask queue. It also will prevent some possible optimisations (or at least make them much harder).

> If yes, to what extent? Is it an issue?

It depends. [Measure it if you care](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). It might not be significant, but still I'd argue that at least it is bad code.